# HTML Validation Error : Element "ui" undefined. (Accessibility)

Tags: html, html-lists, standards, accessibility

In trying to comply with new web accessibility guidelines that some Ontario, Canada establishments must follow we have run some tools to access the changes required. One of the HTML standards being flagged appears as the following:

> **Element "ui" undefined.**
>
> This happens when the version
> of HTML used on this page doesn't support an element with this name.
> This can happen if the element is misspelled, is uppercase or mixed
> case in XHTML, or isn't supported by some HTML versions. For example,
> HTML 4 DOCTYPEs don't allow HTML 5 element and Strict DOCTYPEs don't
> allow stylistic elements and frames which were present in earlier
> versions of HTML.

The lines it points to look like the following:

```
<ui class="global-menu">
```

There are four of these lines, each of which it gives this problem to. What exactly is wrong with these? I've never known any HTML version to not support ui elements. Is this possibly a bug with the validation checker, and should I just ignore it, or is there actually an issue here that needs fixing to be accessible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `<ui>` element in HTML. The class of "global-menu" makes me think you're looking you're looking for a `<ul>` not a `<ui>`.

Comment: Wow, yes that is what I am looking for. This is not my code, I am simply modifying it to make it accessible. I can't believe I missed this simple thing! Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry, I had to stare at it for a few seconds before I figured out that `i != l`

Comment: What is weird though, is that that code would have been taken from an already existing page as this is in the footer. I checked some other pages to see if they had <ui> or <ul> and it would appear they had <ul>, so it is weird that this part has <ui>. Anyway, I will accept as soon as it lets me.

Comment: When a page has a tag like `<ui>`, browsers just ignore it, except that modern browsers generate a DOM node that you can style and script. The `<li>` elements will still be recognized. But regarding accessibility, any special handling that assistive software might have for `<ul>` elements is of course lost.